# Comparing multiple bits between two uint64_t's based on unique type id always returns true

Tags: c++, c++17

I've got a map where keys are entity id's (`uint32_t`) and values are "signatures," aka `uint64_t`'s with certain bits set that represent a type: `std::unordered_map<uint32_t, uint64_t> m_entityComponents{};`

My goal is to write a template function that accepts a variable amount of types and returns whether or not ALL of those types exist inside an entity. Let's call that function `bool hasAllComponents(uint32_t entity)`.

To do this, I've written a method which returns a unique id for each type:

```cpp
template <class T>
uint8_t getTypeId()
{
    static uint8_t s_type = ++m_nextComponentType;
    return s_type;
}
```

And then, given any number of types, I construct a new "signature" by calling `getTypeId()` using a fold expression to set each bit for every type present to 1:

```cpp
template<typename... Types>
uint64_t getTypesSignature()
{
    return ((1 << getTypeId<Types>()) | ... | 0);
}
```

Given these two helper functions, I should be able to check if an entity in my map has all of the passed in types with my `hasAllComponents` method, which uses a bitwise `&` operator to compare the cached signature in the map with the newly created one:

```cpp
template<typename... Types>
bool hasAllComponents(uint32_t entity)
{
    uint64_t signature = getTypesSignature<Types...>();
    return (m_entityComponents[entity] & signature);
}
```

However, `hasAllComponents` still returns true when only some of the bits match, not all. I think the issue might be with my `getTypesSignature` fold logic not setting all bits correctly, although printing out the results looks fine to me. There's a flaw in my logic somewhere and would appreciate any help tracking it down!

Comment: @NathanOliver `getTypeId()` is a template, so there will be a different instantiation for each type that is passed in to the template argument, thus multiple `static` variables defined.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Good call.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are generating a `signature` that contains all the *required* bits set to 1, but you are not correctly checking if the entity's value actually has *all* of those same bits set to 1. You are checking if the value has *any* of those same bits is set to 1 instead.

In this comparison:

```
return (m_entityComponents[entity] & signature);
```

The result of the `&` operator will be a `uint64_t`, which is implicitly convertible to `bool`, so the `return` value will be `true` if the resulting `uint64_t` is non-zero, otherwise it will be `false`.

So, let's say the calculated `signature` is `107` (`b01101011`). That means any combination of values with *any* of those bits set will result in `true`, eg:

```
1:   b00000001 & b01101011 = b00000001, != 0? true
2:   b00000010 & b01101011 = b00000010, != 0? true
4:   b00000100 & b01101011 = b00000000, != 0? false
8:   b00001000 & b01101011 = b00001000, != 0? true
16:  b00010000 & b01101011 = b00000000, != 0? false
32:  b00100000 & b01101011 = b00100000, != 0? true
64:  b01000000 & b01101011 = b01000000, != 0? true
107: b01101011 & b01101011 = b01101011, != 0? true
128: b10000000 & b01101011 = b00000000, != 0? false
255: b11111111 & b01101011 = b01101011, != 0? true
```

To make sure the value has *all* of the required bits are set, you simply need to change the comparison to this instead:

```
return ((m_entityComponents[entity] & signature) == signature);
```

The result will be `true` only if the value has at least *all* of the `signature`'s bits set (it can have more), eg:

```
1:   b00000001 & b01101011 = b00000001, == b01101011? false
2:   b00000010 & b01101011 = b00000010, == b01101011? false
4:   b00000100 & b01101011 = b00000000, == b01101011? false
8:   b00001000 & b01101011 = b00001000, == b01101011? false
16:  b00010000 & b01101011 = b00000000, == b01101011? false
32:  b00100000 & b01101011 = b00100000, == b01101011? false
64:  b01000000 & b01101011 = b01000000, == b01101011? false
107: b01101011 & b01101011 = b01101011, == b01101011? true
128: b10000000 & b01101011 = b00000000, == b01101011? false
255: b11111111 & b01101011 = b01101011, == b01101011? true
```

Comment: You're 100% right, I was doing the bitwise comparison totally wrong. Thanks for the answer and the thorough explanation!